# Query result in Oracle memory or Perl memory?

Tags: oracle, perl, memory, dbi

I am using the [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm) module to fire a `select` query of `Oracle`. Using the `prepare` module of the [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm), the query has been prepared, and then using the `execute` module, the select query is executed.

**My question is:** Once the query is executed, the result is stored in memory till we use any of the `fetchrow` methods to retrieve the result. Till then, the query result is stored in Oracle memory or Perl memory?

As of my understanding, it should be in Oracle memory, I still wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is held in Oracle until you issue your first fetch. However, you should be aware that once you make your first fetch call DBD::Oracle (which I presume you are using) will likely fetch multiple rows back in one go even if you asked for only one (you can see how many with RowsInCache). You can alter the settings used with ora_prefetch_rows, ora_prefetch_memory and ora_row_cache_off.

Answer (score 1):

in the Oracle memory. First hint: you don't have access to that data.
You could test the amount of memory used by your Perl script before and after the `execute` statement to confirm.

See http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/dbi/ch05_01.htm